# Angular CLI to build files outside project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

```
..
 "apps": [
    {
      "outDir": "C:/dist",
      "root": "src",
..
```

I am looking for an option to build my angular 5 + angular/cli app files to a completely separate directory than my project is. Is it possible. Currently with the setup above (.angular-cli.json) I get an error:

```
An asset cannot be written to a location outside the project.
```

Comment: Looks like same issue as this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8613

Answer (score 3):

Use npm scripts in package.json.

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod --stats-json",
    "postbuild-prod": "copyfiles ./dist/**/* c:/dist",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^6.4.2-beta.1",
```

Build with `npm run build-prod`. Anything in `postbuild-prod` gets run after the build.

Ref [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles), install globally.

Answer (score 0):

```
"outDir": "./dist/target/resources",
```

Edit in .angular-cli.json file to above